# Fullcalendar - Scheduler - weekly schedule without actual dates

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I need to put a scheduler in an app that will make a weekly schedule without dates. For example weekly dinner schedule. Or chores schedule, etc. Really just need day of week and time mapped.

Fullcalendar's Scheduler is the perfect format, except it deals with specific dates.

Is there a way I can use it for my use case? Scheduling weekly events without them being tied to specific dates?

Comment: was you able to solve you problem with fullcalendar ?

Comment: no not yet, I probably will have to fake it.